# PHP include showing error

Tags: php, html

I have a huge problem that I'm sure has a pretty simple solution.

I'm writing a few php/html pages (all saved as php files). But, when I attempt to view the pages in a browser, all that's shown is the HTML and stylesheets. In other words, it's as if the php code isn't even there.

It's not even a huge, in depth piece of code. It's only an include statement. However, when I view the source code from the browser (Firefox) it actually shows me an error saying `'Saw <? Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML. (XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML.)'`

I'll throw in a snip of the header I'm trying to include and the page where I included it so you guys can check for syntax, but I'm thinking that syntax isn't the issue.

Here's the header (saved as a .php file)

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="toptitle">
        New Page - Challenge
    </div>
    <div id="toplinks">
        Username: <input type="text" id="user" rows="0" cols="20" maxlength="20"></input> <br>
        Password: <input type="text" id="pass" rows="0" cols="20" maxlength="20"></input> <br>
        <table align="center" cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td> <a href="login.php"> <img src="login.gif" border="0" width="50" height="20" vspace="0"> </a> </td>
                <td> <a href="signup.php"> <img src="signup.gif" border="0" width="50" height="20" vspace="0"> </a> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><hr>
```

And I'm attempting to include it on a page with a simple

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

Any insight would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Are these files sitting on a WAMP/LAMP server that can serve PHP?

Comment: your header.php has no `<?php ... ?>` code blocks so `include()` is simply going to treat it ALL as output. Remember... there's no such thing as a "php script". There's only files which have PHP code blocks embedded within.

Comment: Even with the <?php ... ?> blocks around the code using an echo statement, the header has an issue even coming up on it's own, showing a "; ?> at the end of the page.

Comment: As far as the WAMP server goes, I do have the server running on my computer, but how can I be sure those files are on the server?

Comment: @MarcB The included file doesn't need any PHP in it at all. And there most certainly IS such a thing as a PHP script (you don't need a web server at all to run PHP). My guess is that PHP is not even being used by the server here, and the browser is treating `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` as a malformed XML declaration.

Comment: @user1332364 For WAMP, you should have a folder called "www" under C:\wamp\. Place both the PHP and HTML files there.

Comment: @mike: see how far you get with a simple file that just has `echo 'hello world';` in it. Without `<?php` to switch over to PHP mode, the php interpreter can parse **ANY** file and simply treat is all as output, even if the contents of the file are nothing but legitimate php code.

Comment: @MarcB I guess you are missing my point.  The fact that his include file doesn't have any PHP blocks in it at all (it is purely HTML), is not a problem here at all. Also, you CAN run a PHP script without `<?php ?>` tags if running in CLI mode with `-r` option set or using PHP interactive shell.

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively sure that the file on which you're attempting to include the header is saved as .php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike Brant said it seems that your php is not being used. I think so as well.

The question is now, why it is not being used. Options to start with:

1. check your apache httpd.conf for AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
2. Call the header.php directly (in the browser: http://yourdoma.in/header.php) and check if it shows error messages, which you can check
3. check on general issues: create 2 files:

top.php

```
<?php
  echo "top<BR>";
  include 'sub.php';
?>
```

sub.php

```
<?php
  echo "sub<BR>";
?>
```

What is the output?
If you see a straight forward error message you propably have a webserver error (for apache check httpd.conf).
If it shows top and then an error message it may be a permissions thing - fix it based on the error message.
If you get top and sub there may you are fine in general, but your original files have an issue. If so, copy your files and then strip off code until you can isolate the issue.